# url parsing in php - turning spaces to pluses

Tags: php

is there a php function for doing something like this:
turning this - 701 First Ave, Sunnyvale, CA
to this - 701+First+Ave,+Sunnyvale,+CA
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to replace spaces:

```
$result = str_replace(" ", "+", $source);
```

[Documentation for str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

If you also want to replace other characters that would interfere on the URL (like `?`, `&`, etc)

```
$result = urlencode($source);
```

[Documentation for urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: $source (in this case 'subject') comes last.

Answer (score 2):

`str_replace(" ", "+", $address);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

This is especially designed to encode string to used in URL. There is a mirror function for decoding back as well, just check the doc.

Comment: i had a mistake, i need something that does that in javascript. anything for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceSpaceByPlus($string) {
  return str_replace(" ", "+", $string);
}
```

and use `echo replaceSpaceByPlus($string);` where string it the tekst you want to have replaced (or return, or whatever you want to do with the value.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it? Maybe you're searching for [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Otherwise, for a simple replace go for [str_replace()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), but if you need to url-encode a string, than you should really go for [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) which is more fit, because replaces all the symbols that are not allowed in a URL.